# SSH private key is working on SFTP (FileZilla), but not in the console

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-keys, console

I generated an SSH key using [WebHost Manager's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel#WHM) *"Manage root's SSH keys to be used on SFTP and console SSH connection"*.

FileZilla got connected easily with the private key and password, but when I tried to use it in the console, the password was not allowed.

[[image]]

(I'm not quite sure how SSH keys work, but I have used them before just like I'm doing now and it worked.)

**What is the error with this connection?**

Adding `-vv` to the command, I got this message:

```
comet@cometin:~$ ssh root@************ -p ***** -i /home/comet/Documentos/llave_vps_1.ppk -vv

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "************" port *****
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ************ [************] port *****.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/comet/Documentos/llave_vps_1.ppk type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/comet/Documentos/llave_vps_1.ppk-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ************:***** as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1562/3072
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:Lc/h6wZzvOafLC/Oi20oRyrncCAFGFI1JWF6gP8NtuY
debug1: Host '[************]:*****' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/comet/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1506/3072
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/comet/Documentos/llave_vps_1.ppk ((nil)), explicit
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/comet/Documentos/llave_vps_1.ppk
Enter passphrase for key '/home/comet/Documentos/llave_vps_1.ppk':
```

Answer (score 0):

If FileZilla was able to use the keys and the password, then I assume it works.

I would recommend double checking you are typing the correct password in the console. Try adding -vv to your ssh command like so:

`ssh -vv ...`

If you aren't it will print out a debug message simply saying "bad passphrase given, try again..."

Comment: I updated the question. And I think it should work too, since it worked with filezilla. It is a Key with putty format created by the server I'm trying to connect

Comment: Do you know the password to the private key? I saw from your output, there wasn't anything about you attempting to enter a password like from the first post.

Comment: Yes, I created the password and pasted (and also typed) in both filezilla and SSH. And the last line of the output is the password prompt where I'm not allowed to continue.

Comment: Why or how are you not allowed to continue? Just an fyi, when you type in the password on the console for ssh, it doesn't show any kind of feedback because it's being masked for security purposes, but it is being entered.

Comment: Hi, I know passwords are many times hidden, that is not the problem in this case. I write the correct password, it doesn't work, I try again 2 times and them SSH finishes due to too many invalid attempts.

Comment: It might be worth trying to remove the password from the private key. Try the following and follow the prompts: `ssh-keygen -p -f your_private_key`